# PostId return null when share post by android native app

Tags: android, android-facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm using Facebook SDK 4.2.0 to share my link. I'm using `FacebookCallback` to handler return result.

When `ShareDialog` is displayed, I post my share content and Facebook app shows up a toast saying I shared this post but I received `postId = null`.

So I can't progress my code on method onSuccess(). Please show me how to get postId. Thanks!

Comment: Im using Android SDK

Comment: Post your code if you can to get effective help

Comment: Were you able to fix the issue? I have experiencing the same issue.